# Google map ajax and php

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want load a domain *url* in div element

I have 2 problems :

- if load a domain for example 'google.com' with http protocol don't load address images correctly, but load page !
- if load a google map with https protocol give warning and don't work never !

Here is my code :

**load.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('div').load('/x-request.php?url=googleMapAdress');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**x-request.php**

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('https://' . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

Note: I don't want to use iframe tag & my code must have ajax code!

What is the solution?

//more explain

How get any external page and load it in div element completely ?
this is means => href, src and all links work truly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried you below code and its working as expected.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('div').load('x-request.php?url=maps.google.com');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php code**

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('https://' . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

Its loading Google map without any error.

**Edit**

In response of comment following are the possible best solutions.

The setting you are looking for is `allow_url_fopen`.

set `allow_url_fopen = On`  in php.ini file.

You have two ways of getting around it without changing php.ini, one of them is to use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), and the other is to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

**curl example**

```
function get_content($URL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo get_content('http://example.com');
```

Quick reference links are as below for curl.

http://www.kanersan.com/blog.php?blogId=45

http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

```
<php
$ch = curl_init();// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);
//return the as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
// echo output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$url = $_GET['url'];


$path = 'http://'.$url.'/';
$search = '#url\((?!\s*[\'"]?(?:https?:)?//)\s*([\'"])?#';
$replace = "url($1{$path}";
$output = preg_replace($search, $replace, $output);

echo $output;

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it isn't my Purpose ,googleMapAdress =innuendo=> a address from google.map, how get any external page and load it in div element with ajax completely ?

Comment: when want to get a external page with https protocol, i see this warning : `Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\x-request.php on line 2
Warning: file_get_contents(https://google.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\x-request.php on line 2`

Comment: thanks, but give err again  : `Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to https://google.com:80 (Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\xampp\htdocs\x-request.php on line 2
Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (5)`

Comment: dude i just gave u alternative u can also do it with file_get_contents by just enable allow_url_fopen in php ini...have u tried it...to use fsockopen again u need to enable php_fsockopen

Comment: can you give a code example that load a external page ,i tried but cann't write it !!

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/simpleget.html here are the bunch of example.

Comment: as i told you i have already test your code at myside all you need to do is enable some settings in php.ini and htdocs apachec conf file...THATS IT bro.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22960/discussion-between-geeking-and-dipesh-parmar)